# Why does this bad universal initializer syntax compile and result in unpredictable behavior?

Tags: c++, compilation, initializer-list

I have a bunch of code for working with hardware (FPGA) registers, which is roughly of the form:

```
struct SomeRegFields {
    unsigned int lower : 16;
    unsigned int upper : 16;
};

union SomeReg {
    uint32_t wholeReg;
    SomeRegFields fields;
};
```

(Most of these register types are more complex. This is illustrative.)

While cleaning up a bunch of code that set up registers in the following way:

```
SomeReg reg1;
reg1.wholeReg = 0;
// ... assign individual fields
card->writeReg(REG1_ADDRESS, reg1.wholeReg);

SomeReg reg2;
reg2.wholeReg = card->readReg(REG2_ADDRESS);
// ... do something with reg2 field values
```

I got a bit absent-minded and accidentally ended up with the following:

```
SomeReg reg1{ reg1.wholeReg = 0 };
SomeReg reg2{ reg2.wholeReg = card->readReg(REG2_ADDRESS) };
```

The `reg1.wholeReg =` part is wrong, of course, and should be removed.

What's bugging me is that this *compiles* on both MSVC and GCC. I would have expected a syntax error here. Moreover, sometimes it works fine and the value actually gets copied/assigned correctly, but other times, it will result in a 0 value even if the register value returned is non-0. It's unpredictable, but appears to be consistent between runs which cases work and which don't.

Any idea why the compilers don't flag this as bad syntax, and why it seems to work in some cases but breaks in others? I assume this is undefined behavior, of course, but why would it would *change* behaviors between what often seem like nearly identical calls, often back-to-back?

---

Some compilation info:

If I [run this through Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E51Pfez6x):

```
int main()
{
    SomeReg myReg { myReg.wholeReg = 10 };
    return myReg.fields.upper;
}
```

This is the code GCC trunk spits out for main with optimization off (`-O0`):

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 10
*   mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
*   mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
    movzx   eax, WORD PTR [rbp-2]
    movzx   eax, ax
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

The lines marked with `*` are the only difference between this version and a version without the bad `myReg.wholeReg =` part. MSVC gives similar results, though even with optimization off, it seems to be doing some. In this case, it just causes an extra assignment in and back out of a register, so it still works as intended, but given my accidental experimental results, it must not always compile this way in more complex cases, i.e. not assigning from a compile-time-deducible value.

Comment: `SomeReg reg1{ reg1.wholeReg = 0 };` is the same as `SomeReg reg1 = reg1.wholeReg = 0;`. How is that different from `int a = b = c = 0;`? Where is there UB?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Since C++20 writing to (or reading from) a variable in its own initializer is technically UB per standard and accessing a member before construction started has I think always technically been undefined behavior per standard. Still, I would assume this to work in practice.

Comment: So till c++20 it was ok? Are you sure it's UB in C++20 for PODs?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It is the resolution to [CWG 2256](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2256.html), which I guess is supposed to be applied as DR to previous revisions as well (I don't know for sure). Actually, even before C++20, it was UB for class/aggregate types (including POD ones) as you can see in the replaced wording.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
reg1.wholeReg = card->readReg(REG2_ADDRESS)
```

This is simply treated as an expression. You are assigning the return value of `card->readReg(REG2_ADDRESS)` to `reg1.wholeReg` and then you use the result of this expression (a lvalue referring to `reg1.wholeReg`) to aggregate-initialize the first member of `reg2` (i.e. `reg2.wholeReg`). Afterwards `reg1` and `reg2` should hold the same value, the return value of the function.

Syntactically the same happens in

```
SomeReg reg1{ reg1.wholeReg = 0 };
```

However, here it is technically undefined behavior since you are not allowed to access variables or class members before they are initialized. Practically speaking, I would expect this to usually work nontheless, initializing `reg1.wholeReg` to `0` and then once again.

Referring to a variable in its own initializer is syntactically correct and may sometimes be useful (e.g. to pass a pointer to the variable itself). This is why there is no compilation error.

---

```
int main()
{
    SomeReg myReg { myReg.wholeReg = 10 };
    return myReg.fields.upper;
}
```

This has additional undefined behavior, even if you fix the initialization, because you can't use a union in C++ for type punning at all. That is always undefined behavior, although some compilers might allow it to the degree that is allowed in C. Still, the standard does not allow reading `fields.upper` if `wholeReg` is the active member of the union (meaning the last member to which a value was assigned).

Comment: Sorry, using reg1 to initialize reg2 was a typo (now edited). In all cases, the assignment was to the variable being initialized itself. However, your explanation still makes sense as to why it isn't *quite* a syntax error. Changing from one case to another is still surprising behavior, defined or not. / I was vaguely aware of the type punning issue, but not that it was strictly UB. Unfortunately, I inherited most of this code, and it came from a hardware-oriented guy. I'll have to look into that more, but for now, it does what we need it to do.